# type for ordered tag not working

Tags: html, css

Please consider the following HTML and CSS Code :

HTML :

```
<ol>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li>Sub-Chapter</li>
          <li>Sub-Chapter</li>
        </ol>
      </li>

      <li>Chapter II</li>

      <li> Checking Type A
        <ol type = "A">
          <li>New Sub-Chapter</li>
          <li>New Sub-Chapter</li>
        </ol>
        </li>  


    </ol>

    <ol>
      <li>A New List</li>

    </ol>
```

CSS :

```
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, "."); counter-increment: item }
```

Why don't I see `A` and `B` getting printed for `New Sub Chapter`but 4.1 and 4.2 ?

My [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atsx0d6t/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert your **HTML** and **CSS** file in below way.You can see also in **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/atsx0d6t/8/)**.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
.list {
  display: block
}
.list:before {
  content: counters(item, ".");
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="list">Test</li>
  <li class="list">
    <ol>
      <li class="list" >Sub-Chapter</li>
      <li class="list" >Sub-Chapter</li>
    </ol>
  </li>

  <li>Chapter II</li>

  <li>Checking Type A
    <ol type="A">
      <li>New Sub-Chapter</li>
      <li>New Sub-Chapter</li>
    </ol>
  </li>


</ol>

<ol>
  <li>A New List</li>

</ol>
```